# How to add a transparent logo to the top sidebar of beamer?

Tags: graphics, transparent

This is the code for beamer's sidebar:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz,graphicx} 

\title{Title}
\author{My name}
\institute{My institute}

\useoutertheme[right,height=0pt,width=0.12\paperwidth]{sidebar}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas right}[horizontal shading]    [left=blue!10!white,right=white] 

\makeatletter
\addtobeamertemplate{sidebar right}{}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay] % 
    \node[anchor=north east,xshift=0.8pt,yshift=2pt] at (current page.north east) {\includegraphics[width=0.11\paperwidth]{logo.png}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Frame content
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I want the logo image file(logo.png) to be transparent at the top of the sidebar and not cover the texts, what should I do?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx. can you please give more details as to what you mean by transparent? do you mean that some element of image should be transparent, such as the background? Or do you want the whole image to not be fully opaque?

Comment: in which case, the answer from @Rmano is correct. jpg doesn't support transparency, you need to edit your image and create the transparency layer and save it as a png instead.

Comment: such as this logo:[logo.png](https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-uinvert-dock/256/OS_Ubuntu.png)

Comment: That logo has a correct alpha layer and for me your MWE is correctly compiled withthe tranparency (see last edit in my answer)

Comment: Could we move the title text down and under the logo picture?

Comment: @weirobot026a --- this is a different question.

Answer (score 5):

The `jpg` format has no idea of what transparency is. If you create a `png` image with a proper alpha (transparent) layer, it should simply work.

I have

```
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
\begin{textblock*}{100mm}(.98\textwidth,0.1cm)
    \includegraphics[height=0.9cm]{logo-eb}
\end{textblock*}}
```

(using `\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}`) and it works nicely:

[image]

(and the image is a `.png` with the parts external to the circle marked as transparent).

[image]

#### update

With the new MWE, and your logo, the result is satisfactory:

[image]

If you want that also the orange part (which is *not* transparent in the `.png`) you can

1. edit the PNG image so that it is partially transparent, or
2. add `opacity` like this:

   ```
      \node[anchor=north east,xshift=0.8pt,yshift=2pt,
       opacity=0.3] at (current page.north east) {\includegraphics[width=0.11\paperwidth]{logo.png}};
   ```

   to obtain:

   [image]
3. and/or move the logo down (for example with `yshift=-0.11\paperwidth`:

   [image]

Comment: I have tried this. The logo can be transparent. However, The logo positon cann‘t work well in sidebar.

Comment: @weirobot026a --- difficult to say. If you can post a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) maybe we can help...

Comment: I have slove it by this:`\makeatletter
\addtobeamertemplate{sidebar right}{}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay] % 
        \node[anchor=south east,xshift=0.8pt,yshift=2pt] at (current page.south east) {\includegraphics[width=0.11\paperwidth]{logo.png}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\makeatother`.Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure your `logo.png` has an alpha layer? - the fact that the png can have transparency does not mean that it automatically has it... if you post a question with an MWE and the logo.png  I'll try to help you.

Comment: I have changed my question. And I want the logo file at the top of sidebar.What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: But this png file overlayed the texts.